# Can't Perform a React State update on a unmounted component when passing a state as an prop to the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I am trying to pass a state to the child component.

The State is for

```
loading state
```

Inside the parent component As you can see I am passing set loading as prop

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

return (
<View>
 <IndividualProduct
             info={item[i]}
             index={i}
             key={i}
             fav={true}
             stateChange={stateChange}
             setLoading={setLoading}
             loading={loading}/>
</View>
)
```

Inside the child component
I am getting the props like this

```
const IndividualProduct = ({info, index, fav, stateChange, setLoading}) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const token = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.token);
  const favoriteList = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productReducer.favoriteList,
  );

const addToFav = (IdToSend) => {
    if (token == '') {
      alert('Please sign in to add this product as your favourite.');
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
      let dataToSend = {
        ProductId: `${IdToSend}`,
        ProductLanguageId: 'LANG1',
        ProductVariantId: '',
      };
      dispatch(addFavorite(token.access_token, dataToSend)).then((res) => {
        dispatch(fetchFavorite(tokenData));
        setFavorite(true);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
  };



return(<View>   
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addToFav(info.id)}
              style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
              <Icon2 name="star-o" color="#4684A0" size={40} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
</View>)
```

As you can see I am calling the setLoading when ever I press the button. But when ever its finish

I getting this message

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions
```

Comment: Can you push some sample code on your question. Its easier to find your problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It should work

```
<IndividualProduct setLoading={(input)=> setLoading(input)} />
```